# Can opendir(pathname) change the value of the input pathname?

Tags: c, directory-structure, opendir

I've received some curious results while using `opendir()`:

```
int dtw(char *path) {

    struct stat statbuf;

    ...

    else if (S_ISDIR(statbuf.st_mode)) {
            printf("Path is: %s\n", path);

            struct dirent *dirent;
            DIR *dirp;

            if ((dirp = opendir(path)) == NULL) {
                puts("Can't open directory.");
                return -1;
            }

            printf("Path is: %s\n", path);
    }

    ...
}
```

Results in:

```
Path is: /home/.../etc
Path is:
```

The only thing that would affect `path` is `opendir()` here. Does it have side effects that I'm not seeing? Or is there something else at work?

Comment: How did you declare and initialize `path`?

Comment: `path` is parsed from the command line and eventually passed into the relevant function from `main()`. Question edited to reflect that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No changes are allowed; the definition of [`opendir()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/opendir.html) is:

```
DIR *opendir(const char *dirname);
```

And the `const` says `opendir()` did not change it.

I wonder if your `path` is a pointer to freed memory?  In that case, the memory may have been allocated to `opendir()` and you are seeing the change because you're using a dangling pointer to memory that you should not be looking at?

Comment: Ah, that's exactly it. This is the first time I've come across that kind of problem since switching from Java to C. Thank you very much.